# My timer function is not getting triggered

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created a default timer trigger with the azure core tools CLI

```js
const { app } = require("@azure/functions");

app.timer("timerTrigger2", {
  schedule: "* */5 * * * *",
  handler: (myTimer, context) => {
    context.log("Timer function processed request.");
  },
});
```

But for some reason it won't log the message, nor trigger because I have 0 executions of the function. Why is that happening? Am I missing something from the docs?

Comment: is it not working locally ? or after been deployed?

Comment: @Thomas in the cloud, after been deployed. It simply does not run

Comment: how doy ou deploy your function app ? can you see naything in the log or troubleshooting blade ?

Comment: I'm deploying with the azure tools extension

Answer (score 1):

I have created timer trigger function by using below commands.

```
func init
func new
func start
```

[image]

**Timer trigger function:**

```
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.timer('timerTrigger', {
    schedule: '0 */5 * * * *',
    handler: (myTimer, context) => {
        context.log('Timer function processed request.');
    }
});
```

- I have added storage account connection string in local.settings.json like below:

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "your-storage account conn-string"
  }
}
```

**host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

The above function is executed and triggered successfully and logging the message as well.

[image]

I was successfully deployed the timer trigger function into azure portal. check below:

[image]

The timer trigger function ran successfully in azure as well. check below:
**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That really did the thing locally. But it still doesn't work when deployed. Is the timer trigger not on a most basic plan?

Comment: @SergioRamirez, it will work in any plan but I have tried premium in the above. Can you try by using premium plan?

Comment: I mean, with a premium plan I do see the logs as it gets executed. But with the basic plan it does not unfortunately. So was looking for confirmation on that 

Comment: @SergioRamirez, I have tried with basic consumption plan also, The function executed successfully like [this](https://i.imgur.com/tsyQa7c.png)